# Group an array on the basis of array keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array structure like this,which is coming from a loop:

```
$a = array('9-aug','$50','room1');
$b = array('10-aug','$60','room1');
$c = array('9-aug','$70','room2');
$d = array('10-aug','$80','room2');
```

I need to get the data like this(i.e) group the data on the basis of date:

```
['9-aug-2014']=>{
                [0]=>{'$50','room1'},
                [1]=>{'$70','room2'}

                }

['10-aug-2014']=>{
            [0]=>{'$60','room1'},
            [1]=>{'$80','room2'}

            }
```

Is there any function for this ? I have tried using    array_map,    but can't get the desired o/p.
Here is what I have tried:

```
$e = array_map(null, $a, $b, $c,$d);
print_r($e);
```

And got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9-aug
            [1] => 10-aug
            [2] => 9-aug
            [3] => 10-aug
        )



 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $50
            [1] => $60
            [2] => $70
            [3] => $80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => room1
            [1] => room1
            [2] => room2
            [3] => room2
        )

)
```

Please help.I can't format the `$a,$b,$c,$d` arrays, as this the way the data is fetched.

How do I format the data so that it can be visible in this format.

```
<table class="price-breakdown">
                    <thead>
                    <!--<tr><th></th><th style="font-weight:normal" colspan="3">Price per room (inc VAT &amp; taxes)</th></tr>-->
                    <tr>
                        <th class="date-col">Date</th>
                        <th class="date-col">Room</th>
                            <th valign="top">
                                    Premier Saver
                                <br>
                                <span class="pbThSubtitle">
                                    Price per room<br>(inc VAT &amp; taxes)
                                </span>
                            </th>


                    </tr></thead>

                    <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <nobr>Wed 17 Sep 14</nobr>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">1</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>71.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">2</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>71.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">3</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>71.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <nobr>Thu 18 Sep 14</nobr>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">1</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>67.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">2</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>67.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">3</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>67.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <nobr>Fri 19 Sep 14</nobr>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">1</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>83.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">2</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>83.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">3</td>
                                        <td>
    Â£<span>83.00</span>
                                        </td>


                                </tr>
                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="yellow-top">
                            <td colspan="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="date-col">
                                <nobr>Total 3 nights </nobr>
                            </td>
                            <td>3 rooms</td>

                            <td>    Â£<span>663.00</span>
</td>



                            <td>    Â£<span>744.00</span>
</td>



                            <td>    Â£<span>822.75</span>
</td>


                    </tr><tr class="yellow-btm"><td colspan="5"></td></tr></tfoot>

                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by following code. And working script available at following url: http://sugunan.net/demo/array4.php

```
$a = array('9-aug','$50','room1');
$b = array('10-aug','$60','room1');
$c = array('9-aug','$70','room2');
$d = array('10-aug','$80','room2');

$arr = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
$arr_merge = array();

foreach($arr as $key_dim1=>$val_dim1)
{
    $arr_merge[$val_dim1[0]][] = array($val_dim1[1],$val_dim1[2]);
}

print_r($arr_merge);
```

The table creation part from the array

```
<table class="price-breakdown">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="date-col">Date</th>
            <th class="date-col">Room</th>
            <th valign="top">Premier Saver<br>
            <span class="pbThSubtitle">Price per room<br>(inc VAT &amp; taxes)</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($arr_merge as $key1=>$val1){
            foreach($val1 as $key2=>$val2){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><nobr><?php if($key2==0){ echo $key1; } ?></nobr></td>
                <td align="left"><?php echo $val2[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $val2[0]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried to fetch the data so that it could format in the above table, but could not. What to change?

Comment: Table creation function also added in the answer. and you can see the real table also in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your data source has keys that are duplicates - I don't know if this was intentional or just to pad out the data.

Here is a function that can handle it, if the keys were unique:

```
<?php
$a = array('9-aug','$50','room1');
$b = array('10-aug','$60','room1');
$c = array('9-sept','$70','room2');
$d = array('10-sept','$80','room2');
$final = firstKeyAsKey(array($a, $b, $c, $d));

function firstKeyAsKey(array $joined) {
    $cleanedArr = array();
    foreach($joined as $key => $arr) {
        if(is_array($arr) && isset($arr[0])) {
            $outerKey = $arr[0];
            unset($arr[0]);
            $cleanedArr[$outerKey] = $arr;
        }
    }
    return $cleanedArr;
}

// dump result
var_dump($final);
?>
```

**Also.**

If you actually want the nested arrays to be objects instead, add this patch:

```
<?php
$cleanedArr[$outerKey] = json_decode(json_encode($arr), FALSE);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I got. The other answer is similar. This returns exactly what you had requested.

```
$a = array('9-aug','$50','room1');
$b = array('10-aug','$60','room1');
$c = array('9-aug','$70','room2');
$d = array('10-aug','$80','room2');
$fullArray[] =$a;
$fullArray[] =$b;
$fullArray[] =$c;
$fullArray[] =$d;
function makeNewArray($array){
foreach($array as $x){
   $newarray[$x[0]][]="{'".$x[1]."','".$x[2]."'}";
}
return $newarray;
}
$result= makeNewArray($fullArray);
print_r($result);
```